# Callable is invalid base class?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

Can someone explain why inheriting from unparameterized and parameterized `Callable`:

```
from typing import Callable
from typing import NoReturn
from typing import TypeVar


T = TypeVar('T', str, int)
C = Callable[[T], NoReturn]


class Foo(Callable):

    def __call__(self, t: T):
        pass


class Bar(C):

    def __call__(self, t: T):
        pass
```

when passed to mypy raises errors for both `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
tmp.py:13: error: Invalid base class
tmp.py:19: error: Invalid base class
```

Comment: @PatrickHaugh a toy example: https://gist.github.com/phuntimes/5b19e3cd76ccccaf51e41005dacd2b86

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Callable classes share common init and validation, but have incompatible argument types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is in part because classes at runtime can't really inherit from a function or a callable to begin with, and in part because you don't need to explicitly inherit from `Callable` to indicate that a class is callable.

For example, the following program typechecks as expected using mypy 0.630:

```
from typing import Callable, Union, NoReturn, List

class Foo:
    def __call__(self, t: Union[str, int]) -> NoReturn:
        pass


class FooChild(Foo): pass


class Bad:
    def __call__(self, t: List[str]) -> NoReturn:
        pass


def expects_callable(x: Callable[[Union[str, int]], NoReturn]) -> None: 
    pass


expects_callable(Foo())         # No error
expects_callable(FooChild())    # No error
expects_callable(Bad())         # Error here: Bad.__call__ has an incompatible signature
```

Basically, if a class has a `__call__` method, it's implicitly assumed that class is also a callable.

Comment: Is there a way to suppress the check on the class declaration line?

Comment: @SeanMcVeigh -- sorry, which check are you referring to?

Comment: Why does mypy even raise an error given that subclassing Callable is really to take advantage of `ABCMeta`

Comment: sorry, i mean whatever raises `error: Invalid base class`

Comment: @SeanMcVeigh -- I guess you could add on a `# type: ignore` comment to that line. Alternatively, you could not inherit from Callable and just mark Foo's `__call__` as an abstract method (e.g. using abc's `@abstractmethod` decorator). That would let you mandate all subclasses implement `__call__` with a specific signature.