# Python how to type hint a Callable with __wrapped__

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, static-typing, callable-object

When passing around functions, I normally type hint them with [`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable).

The docs for [`collections.abc.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Callable) state that it has four dunder methods:

> class collections.abc.Callable
>
> ABCs for classes that provide respectively the methods `__contains__()`, `__hash__()`, `__len__()`, and `__call__()`.

At one point, I want to check if there is a `__wrapped__` attribute on a function.  This works fine at runtime via a check with `hasattr(func, "__wrapped__")`.

When static type checking with `mypy`, it reports: `error: "Callable[..., Any]" has no attribute "__wrapped__"  [attr-defined]`.  This makes sense to me, as `Callable` isn't supposed to have a `__wrapped__` attribute.

How can I properly type hint a `Callable` with a `__wrapped__` attribute?  Is there some other type hint or workaround I can do?

---

**Code Sample**

I am using `mypy==0.782` and `Python==3.8.2`:

```py
from functools import wraps
from typing import Callable


def print_int_arg(arg: int) -> None:
    """Print the integer argument."""
    print(arg)


@wraps(print_int_arg)
def wrap_print_int_arg(arg: int) -> None:
    print_int_arg(arg)
    # do other stuff


def print_is_wrapped(func: Callable) -> None:
    """Print if a function is wrapped."""
    if hasattr(func, "__wrapped__"):
        # error: "Callable[..., Any]" has no attribute "__wrapped__"  [attr-defined]
        print(f"func named {func.__name__} wraps {func.__wrapped__.__name__}.")


print_is_wrapped(wrap_print_int_arg)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously the easy answer is to add a `# type: ignore` comment.  However, this isn't actually solving the problem, IMO.

I decided to make a type stub for a callable with a `__wrapped__` attribute.  Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52654516/11163122), here is my current solution:

```py
from typing import Callable, cast


class WrapsCallable:
    """Stub for a Callable with a __wrapped__ attribute."""

    __wrapped__: Callable

    __name__: str

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...


def print_is_wrapped(func: Callable) -> None:
    """Print if a function is wrapped."""
    if hasattr(func, "__wrapped__"):
        func = cast(WrapsCallable, func)
        print(f"func named {func.__name__} wraps {func.__wrapped__.__name__}.")
```

And `mypy` now reports `Success: no issues found in 1 source file`.

I feel as if this is a lot of boiler-plate code, and would love a more streamlined answer.

Answer (score 2):

Mypy complain on use of `__wrapped__` in print statement.
The following trick makes mypy happy

```
def print_is_wrapped(func: Callable) -> None:
    """Print if a function is wrapped."""
    if hasattr(func, "__wrapped__"):
        wrapped_name = getattr(func, "__wrapped__").__name__
        print(f"func named {func.__name__} wraps {wrapped_name}.")
```

Comment: Hello @Serg and thank you for the answer!  However, in the above code, if you enter `reveal_type(wrapped_name)`, it prints `Any`, meaning the reason `mypy` is silent is because it can't infer the type of `wrapped_name` properly.  In my opinion, this is no better than a `# type: ignore` comment.